# mysql join not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables: "users" and "posts." The posts table has a 'post' column and a 'poster_id' column. I'm working on a PHP page that shows the latest posts by *everyone*, like this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id < '$whatever' LIMIT 10
```

This way, I can print each result like this:

```
id: 43, poster_id:'4', post: hello, world
id: 44, poster_id:'4', post: hello, ward
id: 45, poster_id:'5', post: oh hi!
etc...
```

Instead of the id, I would like to display the NAME of the poster (there's a column for it in the 'users' table)

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE id < '$whatever' 
       INNER JOIN users 
           ON posts.poster_id = users.id LIMIT 10
```

Is this the correct type of join for this task? Before learning about joins, I would query the users table for each post result. The result should end up looking similar to this:

```
id: 43, poster_id:'4', name:'foo', post: hello, world
id: 44, poster_id:'4', name:'foo', post: hello, ward
id: 45, poster_id:'5', name:'fee', post: oh hi!
etc...
```

Thanks for helping in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WHERE` clause must come after the `FROM` clause.

```
SELECT  posts.*, users.*   // select your desired columns
FROM    posts 
        INNER JOIN users ON posts.poster_id = users.id 
WHERE   id < '$whatever'
LIMIT   10
```

the SQL Order of Operation is as follows:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause
- ORDER BY clause

**UPDATE 1**

For those *column names that exists on both tables*, add an `ALIAS` on them so it can be uniquely identified. example,

```
SELECT  post.colName as PostCol, 
        users.colName as UserCol, ....
FROM ....
```

on the example above, both tables has column name `colName`. In order to get them both, you need to add alias on them so in your front end, use `PostCol` and `UserCol` to get their values.

Comment: thank you. I seem to have a problem with this. there are some fields in 'posts' and 'users' that are the same, and when I am printing them, I get the wrong column (like from users instead posts) how can I avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
INNER JOIN users ON posts.poster_id = users.id
WHERE posts.id < '$whatever'
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the syntax a little incorrect.

Should be

```
SELECT * FROM posts
INNER JOIN users ON posts.poster_id = users.id
WHERE id < '$whatever' LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers already given tell you the main reason for your query not working at all (ie the `WHERE` clause should come after the `JOIN` clauses), however, I'd like to make a couple of additional points:

- I would suggest using an `OUTER JOIN` for this. It probably won't make much difference, but in the event of a post record having an invalid `poster_id`, an `INNER JOIN` will mean the record is dropped from the results, whereas an `OUTER JOIN` will mean that the record is included, but the values from the `users` table will be `null`. I imagine you don't want to ever have an invalid `poster_id` on the `posts` table, but broken data does happen even in the best regulated system, and it is helpful in these cases to still get the data from the query.
- I would strongly suggest not doing `SELECT *`, and instead itemising the fields you want to get back from the query. `SELECT *` has a number of problems, but it's particularly bad when you have multiple tables in the query, because if you have fields with the same name on both tables, (eg `id`), then it becomes very hard to distinguish which one you're working with, as your PHP recordset won't include the table reference. Itemising the fields may make your query string longer, but it won't make it any slower - if anything it'll be quicker - and it will be easier to work with in the long run.

Neither of these points are essential; the query will work without them (as long as you switch the `WHERE` clause to after the `JOIN`), but they may improve your query and hopefully also improve your understanding of SQL.